How do I prevent a bottom sheet from sliding up into the status bar area in an edge to edge app
I have a View/XML based app where edge to edge is enabled. One of my screens consists of a CoordinatorLayout and within that CoordinatorLayout I have a FrameLayout which holds the bottom sheet content. This FrameLayout has a match_parent height.
The problem is, when I fully expand the bottom sheet, it expands to the very top edge of the screen and the status bar overlaps it. Instead, I'd like the bottom sheet to stop expanding when it hits the bottom edge of the status bar. But I still want to keep the rest of this screen edge to edge, so setting android:fitsSystemWindows="true" on the CoordinatorLayout is not an option.
I basically want to do what Google Maps does where the screen is edge to edge but the bottom sheet stops expanding at the bottom edge of the status bar.

